# How to alert myself if the weather changes in the next three hours

Tags: exception, alert, monitor, weather

Can anyone advise how to get this project started if what I want is

1. some gadgets/app/program to scan maybe weather.com continuously
2. when there is a categorical change say from dry to rain three hours later
3. send an alert to my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use service worker for this purpose when your data update or meet certain limit you will get notified

> https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications